# Cannot take photos, message pops up that says "Not enough storage space"

Tags: ios, icloud, photos, camera, storage

I am trying to take a picture and my iPhone 4s says there is not enough storage space and to go to settings.

I went into setting and into iCloud and deleted the prior backpack to free up space and I now I have 5.0 GB.  I also deleted all my rash in my emails, and photos I had via text, and I also deleted all photos from the camera roll.  It still says not enough room.

Comment: its actually some deleted photos which are actually not deleted ... follow this youtube video and clear you GHOST Photos which are not visible but take lot of space on your device

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WT3Z0Hals4

hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't referring to storage on iCloud but on your device itself.

1. Go to `Settings > General > Usage`
2. Under Storage (which is above iCloud) you will get a list of all the apps by size. If there is one you don't use you can delete it to get space to take a picture. If you don't see a list of apps, your phone is probably processing through and you will see a spinning indicator until it finishes:

[image: spinning grey indicator image]

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem and now i think i fixed it. Just for your info i also tried deleting old pictures etc etc and it still says i cant take photos because not enough space (grrr)

Solution: i just switched my phone off and turned it back on!

This must be a bug....

Comment: Thanks this cold reboot is what I needed.  I have been struggling with the fact that deleting photos and videos does not seem to delete them.  This is all I found that helped me with that problems.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After navigating to Settings > General > Usage as suggested by @dwightk at the top of the page you will see your Storage Available and Used. If your Storage Available is too low, you will not be able to take any more photos.

Underneath this then is a list of all the storage space used by Apps, and how much each App uses. This list is sorted in descending order so the *worst offenders* are displayed at the top.

If you click on each App in turn it will take you to a page specific for that App, and depending on the App it will either just show you details of the storage used (eg Photos and Camera), or also may include an option for you to delete the relevant data (eg Videos).